# PHP: When does the user agent show up as Chrome Generic?

Tags: php, user-agent, browscap

I am using the latest php_browscap.ini and the get_browser() function.

A reasonable proportion of my user agents are showing up with Chrome Generic in the parent field, and nothing in the version, major version, or minor version fields.  The proportion is around 10%.

Under what circumstances is Chrome Generic used? For example, is it when the browser version is more up to date than the browscap file?  Is it when the user agent only provides a partially complete record?  Or some other circumstance?

Comment: Why don't you look at some of the user agents that produce this result? I suspect the version will just be missing.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I can't isolate which of the input records relates to the given outputs.

Comment: Why not? Can't you just add something like `if ($browser == "Chrome Generic") { echo $user_agent; }` to the code?

Comment: Or append that info to a log file if the PHP is not being called to return a browser web page.